# how to start fragment from adapter class

Tags: android, android-fragments

trying to start fragment from adapter class using this code

```
public void startFragment(Context context, int position) {
    Activity activity = (Activity) context;
    android.app.FragmentManager manager = activity.getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    DepartmentDetails departmentDetails = new DepartmentDetails();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("id", departmentList.get(position).id);
    bundle.putSerializable("details", departmentList);
    departmentDetails.setArguments(bundle);

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, departmentDetails);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

but it underlines red on `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, departmentDetails);`

and while executing it shows

```
Error:(90, 28) error: no suitable method found for add(int,DepartmentDetails)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment)
```

here is fragment i am using..

```
public class DepartmentDetails extends Fragment implements CallBacks{

    ImageView ivProfile;
    TextView tvName, tvBasicInfo, tvDescription;
    String id, dean;
    Departments details;
    ArrayList<String> faculty, programs;

    RequestParams params;
    MyHttp myHttp;
    String url;

    public DepartmentDetails() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
```

Comment: what is DepartmentDetails Fragment or SupportFragment?

Comment: Its simple Fragment

Comment: please update answer and add DepartmentDetails fragment

Comment: argument mismatch; DepartmentDetails cannot be converted to Fragment, I think something is wrong with DepartmetDetails as @Mohit Suthar said post code of DepartmentDetails

Comment: i have added DepartmentDetails code.. please have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can open fragment from adapter class using below code;

```
  Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
  FragmentManager fm = context.getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
  ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add in your DepartmentDetails fragment class

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment ;
```

instead of

```
  import  android.app.Fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following code.

```
  Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
  ft.commit();
```

Comment: may be now if `getSupportFragmentManager` is not coming make it as `context.getSUpportFragmentManager`