# How to add fragment to recyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to add `fragment` to each item of my `recyclerView`
Here is my `adapter`:

```
    @NonNull
  @Override
  public ViewH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_widget_recyclerview, parent, false);
    return new ViewH(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewH holder, int position) {
     WidgetSavedPaymentsFragment fragment = new WidgetSavedPaymentsFragment();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(holder.mFrameLayoutFragmentContainer.getId(),fragment).commit();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mWidgets.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

public class ViewH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    @BindView(R.id.fragment_container)
    FrameLayout mFrameLayoutFragmentContainer;

    public ViewH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is my mistake..Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please, don't add your code as an image but as text, with the proper markdown formatting. It will be much more helpful to whoever wants to answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to start fragment from adapter class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934817/how-to-start-fragment-from-adapter-class)

Comment: take a look at this it will solve this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45934924/9857545

Comment: I tried but again the same error

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08009d (mobile.uzcard.uz.uzcard:id/fragment_container) for fragment WidgetSavedPaymentsFragment{1168ca7 #1 id=0x7f08009d} here error with fragmentmanager or WidgetSavedPaymentsFragment?

Answer (score 0):

change R.id.fragment_container with holder.mFrameLayoutFragmentContainer

Comment: please mark it as answered if this solves your problem

Comment: I can't use holder.mFrameLayoutFragmentContainer.Here I needed id I think

Comment: ((FragmentActivity) view.getContext()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).commit();

Comment: try this it might help

Comment: ((FragmentActivity) view.getContext()). what is view here?